# RODBC cannot find MS Access Database [RStudio/R]

Tags: r, ms-access, odbc, rstudio

Prior to upgrading to Windows 10, I was using RODBC to establish a connection within RStudio to a MS Access database.

After upgrading to Windows 10, my workflow is halted when I try to make the same connection to the same MS Access database.

> db <- "//svr/userdatabases/database.accdb"
>
> ## Make a connection to the database
>
> con2 <- odbcConnectAccess2007(db)
>
> [RODBC] ERROR: state IM002, code 0, message [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specifiedODBC connection failed>

I have confirmed that the database is located in the correct path (db).

Several sources have suggested that there is an issue with LD_LIBRARY_PATH, but I do not know how to implement the solutions discussed in these threads:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200654626-odbcDriverConnect-works-in-R-but-not-RStudio

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/211021467-Can-t-connect-to-SQL-database-using-RODBC-through-Rstudio-but-can-using-R-in-shell-

How do I implement the solution described in the second link? Specifically, how do I I had create a file "~/.Renviron" and add the following line:

> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/local/nz/lib64/

According to that link, my issue is the ld library path within my rsession is not the same as my bash.

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* This is a site where programmers *write their own code* and share issues with a *specific* coding problem. See the [tour], and a list of what's on-topic at the [help/on-topic] as well as "[ask]".  Your question may be suitable to another [se] site like SuperUser or ServerFault.

Comment: @ashleedawg did you read my post? I wrote my own code. I upgraded software. The code I wrote no longer works. I am asking for help with a solution. Thanks.

Comment: We see you didn't take the tour, not only in question, so follow ashlee's advices! Prior OS was x86 and Office too? And now? You know odbc x86 <> odbc x64. Your DSN needs to be configured on the ODBC with the bitnes of Office. (Driver too).

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing the driver for the correct bit version of your database for RStudio to make the system connection. If your system connection works in R, but not R Studio, installing the correct driver from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734 might solve your issue.